# How do I tell nifty GUI where my fonts files are?

Tags: java, fonts, assets, nifty-gui

I'm tired of using the default fonts bundled in the default style jar, so I figured it'd be as easy as downloading some bitmap font files and specifying which one I wanted to use by there path relative to the workspace.

e.g.

```
//inside of a ScreenBuilder init
//...
control(new LabelBuilder("score"){{
    alignCenter();
    font("font/13-Nimbus.fnt");
    color("#f00f");
    backgroundColor("#3300af");
    text("foobar");
    width((wGUI/3-10)+"px");
    height((hGUI-10)+"px");
}});
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: font/13-Nimbus.fnt    at
>   de.lessvoid.nifty.tools.resourceloader.NiftyResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(NiftyResourceLoader.java:72)
>   ...

So this leads me to believe there is some of add-resource-location function I should be calling to tell nifty where my fonts are. But after looking through the Javadoc I can't find any such function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that font/13-Nimbus.fnt is in your classpath. The way we've set it up it an assets source directory that contains font/etc.fnt

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! That fixes the initial problem (no more error), but the text using the new font doesn't appear. Any chance this problem also has a quick solution?

Comment: If you add the screen source, I might have time to look into it later today.

Comment: Or the complete java source if you're building it there.

Comment: I'd feel bad making you answer a different question in a comment, so I made a seperate question if your still interested: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14510730/821806 thanks again!